# Wildfly 10 @Resource Missing/Unavailable Dependencies

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

From wildfly 10 documentation:

> For example, the following jms-queue "testQueue" is bound to
>   "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test" which means a remote client would
>   look-up this {{kms-queue} using "jms/queue/test". A local client could
>   look it up using "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test",
>   "java:jms/queue/test", or more simply "jms/queue/test"

In my MDB if I use

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ")
Queue testQ;
```

It works fine, But on trying out the following:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jms/queue/TestQ")
Queue testQ;
```

or

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jms/queue/TestQ")
Queue testQ;
```

I get the following error while deploying the application in wildfly 10

> {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.app.app.env.\"com.example.jms.ExampleMdb\".testQ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:jms.queue.TestQ]"]}

What could be the problem? and if I use **java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ** will it work well with other servers other than wildfly?

Comment: Try `lookup` rather than `mappedName`.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the javadoc for Resource it says:

> A product specific name that this resource should be mapped to.
>   The name of this resource, as defined by the `name`
>   element or defaulted, is a name that is local to the application
>   component using the resource.  (It's a name in the JNDI
>   `java:comp/env` namespace.)  Many application servers
>   provide a way to map these local names to names of resources
>   known to the application server.  This mapped name is often a
>   *global* JNDI name, but may be a name of any form.

so for mappedName you can only use a full jndi name or the name in java:comp/env.

what you probably want is:

```
@Resource(lookup = "queue/TestQ")
Queue testQ;
```

And then in your configuration set it up like this:

```
<jms-queue name="classReportQueue">
    <entry name="queue/TestQ"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ"/>
</jms-queue>
```

Comment: Still not working: `@Resource(lookup = "jms/queue/TestQ")` and my wildfly has this entry `<jms-queue name="TestQ" entries="jms/queue/TestQ java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ"/>` and am getting the same error.

Comment: I assume you aren't putting two names under a parameter called entries right? That was just for the comment? Have you looked in the admin console or cli to make sure it's registering the jndi names you expect?

Comment: It is registered  and actually from standalone application i can get it using `Queue testQ = (Queue) context.lookup("jms/queue/TestQ");` my problem is why is it that with `@Resource(mappedName = "java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ")` it is ok, while if i try the other options i get the missing dependency from wildfly